# session_regenerate_id and security attributes

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a strange issue where after I regenerate a session ID using

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

The cookie seems to lose its "Secure, HttpOnly" flags.

I can reset the cookie by using

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), 0, $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    true,  // this is the secure flag you need to set. Default is false.
    true  // this is the httpOnly flag you need to set

);
```

but veracode (who we use for security testing) is flagging it at unsure because the first cookie (the one that is regenerated) does not have the secure, HttpOnly tags in the header.

Here is the sample header

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2018 12:56:41 GMT
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Location: home.php
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=18a289a6c8d34b0df72dafc9d5e12c92; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=18a289a6c8d34b0df72dafc9d5e12c92; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

Veracode is flagging the issue because the first cookie - does not have the secure, httpOnly tags.  I guess its only reading the first, or it feels that them not showing up by default is insecure..How do I go about forcing those tags on a regenerated session? Or is there a better way to achieve what they ask? Here is my code.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_start(); //Not sure if this is needed

session_regenerate_id(true);
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), 0, $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    true,  // this is the secure flag you need to set. Default is false.
    true  // this is the httpOnly flag you need to set

);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your local folder PHP.ini settings (typically called `user.ini` and found in your root HTML directory of your website account), you can set the PHP.ini values:

```
session.cookie_secure=1
session.cookie_httponly=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

and this will mean any usage of session cookies by this account (this website) will conform to the above requirements.

This is much better than coding these reqirements in to your scripts as this can be easily missed or overlooked down the line.

Your script can then be:

```
session_start();
...
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

And you will know everything else will be taken care of automatically.

---

You can read a little more about session security [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you

Comment: Is the user_only_cookies important for security? I know its a side note question

Comment: @RobertDickey it stops sessions being stamped into the URL, [read more here](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2013/05/improve-php-session-cookie-security/)

Comment: It does not directly effect your situation but is a good practise and should be implemented in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
session_set_cookie_params ( int $lifetime [, string $path 
       [, string $domain [, bool $secure = FALSE [, bool $httponly = FALSE ]]]] )
```

before `session_start()`

The `session_unset, destroy and start` is not needed then. Also don't assign a value to `$_SESSION` as you are overwriting the session data.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: I just tested it, but it doesn't seem to change that when I use regenerate_session_id i lose those true attributes I would like to keep

Comment: First use `session_set_cookie_params` the `session_start` and then `session_regenerate_id`. Then it should work